# Rails nested routes navigation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have nested routes

```
resources :events do
    resources :registrations
end
```

Page `/events/1/registrations` shows all the registrations for event 1.
I'd like to have a form on this page or maybe a select box with a link to navigate to `/events/n/registrations`.

Actually, I came up with select_tag, link_to and js setting link's href on select_tag change. But I suspect it's overkill.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a scope/method to your event model that finds the next model in the list and link to that?

```
class Event
  # ...
  scope :next_event, -> { where('id > ?', id).first } # change logic as required
end
```

Then in your view you can simply link to it

```
# ... /app/views/events/show.html....
# NOTE: assumes there is an event.title field
= link_to @event.next_event.title, events_registrations_path(@event.next_event)
```

Be aware that this will do a seperate load of the next event, note recommended to be used in a list. In a production app you'd probably load this as part of a decorator for this particular scenario.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Not particularly what I'm looking for. I'd like also to navigate for example from third event's registrations to the first.